# Adding more than one database value to comboBox on the same row - How?

Tags: c#, mysql

Currently this code only shows the value of the "id" in database, how do i make it so it shows both "id" and "name" values in same row, like "5 - John Carpenter" ?

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=rootpassword";
        string Query = "select * from database2.employee where id='" + comboBox1.Text + "' ORDER BY Auto  ;";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
```

Comment: The code afterwards is for when you click the row in comboBox, it to fill some textboxes with the correct values. (from database)

Answer (score 0):

**1.**  use parametrised queries to avoid `SQL injection` attacks.
**2.** call `Read()` function on `MySqlDataReader` Object to read the `select` query results.
**3.** use `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` instead of `ComboBox1.Text` to get the selected Item from combobox.

Try This:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=rootpassword";
        string Query = "select * from database2.employee where id=@id ORDER BY Auto  ;";

        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);            
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        MySqlDataReader myReader=cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
        if(myReader.Read())
       {
          TextBox1.Text=myReader["id"].ToString() +" - "+myReader["name"].ToString();
        }
      conDataBase.Close();
    }
```